# Many to many relationships in Entity Framework 7 beta 8

Tags: annotations, ef-code-first, many-to-many, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Is there any way to do a many to many relationship (Fluent API or annotations) in EF7 beta 8 without create a join table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is currently an EF7 backlog work item. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1368